# Quota limit for my subscription in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, quota

I have a pay-as-you-go subscription on Microsoft Azure, which was upgraded from a free trial.

When I try to deploy a new virtual machine, it is blocked because my quota limit has been reached. However I only have one single resource group with one NC6 VM, with 6 CPU cores (= 6 CPU quota?)

My understanding is that a standard subscription should have an initial limit of 20 CPU quotas, so I am afraid my subscription still has the CPU quota limit from the free trial subscription.

This should be easy to check, by looking at my quota limits and usage. However I cannot find this information!

Where can I look up how many CPU quotas I am currently using, and what is my maximum limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are GPU cores quotas as well, you should raise a support ticket to increase gpu core quota.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu#deployment-considerations
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request

Comment: And how can I check my current GPU quota usage and limits?

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: these links only say that limits exist, and how to request extensions of said limits. My question is about how to inform myself what exactly those limits are for my subscription, and what my current quota usage is.

Comment: second article describes how to check your quota. Subscriptions > select subscription > Usage + quotas. please, read the linked articles.

Comment: honestly its only because you explained that the info is there; the link does not say anything about it